# how to run spring boot java application in azure databricks

Tags: spring-boot, databricks, azure-databricks

I am looking for guidance into how to run a Spring Boot based java application in Azure Databricks.

I am used to running Spring Boot based java applications in Apache Spark on premise: Spring Boot applications won't run as is in Apache Spark. To get them to run the technique that works for me is

1. rename the original jar file that gets generated by the spring-boot-maven-plugin, using the copy-rename-maven-plugin

```xml
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>rename-file</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>rename</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sourceFile>target/${project.name}-${project.version}.jar.original</sourceFile>
              <destinationFile>target/${project.name}-${project.version}-original.jar</destinationFile>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

2. have a configuration item for the original jar file name and location which is set to the installed location of the original jar file
3. pass the original file name and location to the spark session "-Doriginal.jar-file" in the spark-submit command

```java
sparkConf.setJars(new String[]{props.getJarFile()});
```

4. run using spark submit

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dspring.profiles.active=dev" SparkPiBoot-0.0.1.jar
```

This technique is outlined in https://radanalytics.io/assets/my-first-radanalytics-app/sparkpi-java-spring.html where it is used with an open shift build.

With this technique my driver application runs in on premise Apache Spark as a fully fledged Spring Boot application with dependency injection etc etc. Dataframe code runs in Apache Spark and is taken from the original unmanipulated jar file, so no dependency injection etc.

In Azure Databricks I intend the Databricks job to be scheduled to run from an Azure Data Factory pipeline, so I have tried the same technique: I have installed the 2 jars files in the azure databricks file system, created a Azure Data Factory Databricks Activity with a user property pointing the to original jar file in dbfs.

This results in an error, the application won't run
'''
command--1:1: error: Class org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner not found - continuing with a stub.
io.radanalytics.SparkPiBootApplication.main(Array())
^
'''

The main jar file is a Spring Boot uber jar which contains all the dependent jars including spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar which includes org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner.

Answer (score 3):

I received this answer from Microsoft support:
Databricks classloader does not support loading classes from the Spring Boot uber jar.

There is a workaround which involves

1. Replace default spring jar installed in databricks cluster with required version using these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/libraries/replace-default-jar-new-jar
2. Use the maven-shade-plugin to build the jar

```xml
<build>
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
           <dependencies>
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
               </dependency>
           </dependencies>
           <configuration>
               <keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>false</keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>
               <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
               <filters>
                   <filter>
                       <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                       <excludes>
                           <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                           <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                           <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                       </excludes>
                   </filter>
               </filters>
               <transformers>
                   <transformer
                           implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                       <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                   </transformer>
                   <transformer
                           implementation="org.springframework.boot.maven.PropertiesMergingResourceTransformer">
                       <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                   </transformer>
                   <transformer
                           implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                       <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                   </transformer>
                   <transformer
                           implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                   <transformer
                           implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                       <mainClass>${main-class}</mainClass>
                   </transformer>
               </transformers>
           </configuration>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <phase>package</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>shade</goal>
                   </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
```

Comment: I have persisted with this approach and have solved the following problems along the way in addition to upgrading the  spring framework version in cluster
1) upgraded snake yaml version in cluster
2) disabled logging system in application : org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem=none
disable Gson auto configuration: @SpringBootApplication(
  exclude = { org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration.class }
)
3) removed log4j2 dependencies from shaded jar, uses log4j in cluster

Comment: ...
5) use slf4j api in my code to provide independence from log4j and log4j2
6) remove log4j and log4j2 configuration files, rely on defaults
7) can't use AOP annotations for monitoring on code running sql queries because interferes with spark session, use intermediate class instead for monitoring which then call the query code
8) @Component classes need to be public, may or may not need to be Serializable
9) need cluster per application as applications are deployed in cluster as libraries and all are added to the classpath common to all

Comment: Your comments are really helpful. You should add these points too to the answer, then the entire thing will be in one place.